# htaccess rewrite rule with 2 variables (1 optional)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm aware this has already been asked, but I've tried countless solutions but I'm still not getting the desired result.

I've a page which shows a list of names and the variables data are the starting letter (variable l which can also be a number) and the page number (page_no) and the page number is optional as it should not be displayed in the page 1.

The original URL is the following

```
https://www.example.com/allnames.php?l=A&page_no=1
```

I've the following rule

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^l=([\w]+)$
RewriteRule ^allnames.php$ /allnames/%1? [R=301,L]
```

which works fine for page 1, but it doesn't include the page_no variable, so I tried this one but I'm unable to understand what's wrong.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^l=([\w]+)?page_no=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^allmovies.php$ /allmovies/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
```

the result expected would be, for example

`allnames/A` or `allnames/A/1` for letter `A`, page `1`

`allnames/S/8` for letter `S`, page `8`

And the following is the content of the htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

# to prevent loops
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200

#remove index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

# Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by apache
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]

RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]

# allnames.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^l=([\w]+)$
RewriteRule ^allnames.php$ /allnames/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule allnames/ /allnames.php?l=$1&page_no=$2 [L]
```

Comment: What is the URL being requested? URL parameters are usually separated by `&`, but your regex does not allow for this? You state a "starting letter", however, your regex matches any number of letters?

Comment: I assume you already have the necessary directive(s) to rewrite the request back to `/allnames.php?l=A&page_no=1`?

Comment: @MrWhite yes, I also have the following rewrite rule RewriteRule allnames/ /allnames.php?l=$1&page_no=$2

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^l=([\w]+)?page_no=([0-9]+)$
> ```

The regex in the *condition* (*CondPattern*) does not allow for the `&` delimiter between URL parameters. You are also allowing the `l` parameter value to be entirely omitted (which would result in an ambiguous URL) or contain multiple characters (which you've stated should be a single "letter").

You would seem to need something like the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^l=([\w])&page_no=([0-9]+)$
```

But note that this will fail if the `l` parameter value contains more than one character (or is omitted entirely).

> the result expected would be, for example
>
> `allnames/A` or `allnames/A/1` for letter `A`, page `1`

Note that you would still need your first rule (without the `page_no` URL param) to get `allnames/A`. You could instead make `page_no` optional in the second rule, but you would still get a trailing slash (ie. `allnames/A/`) if that is an issue?

Comment: I've just tried this solution, but unfortunately I can still see the original URL https://www.website.com/allnames.php?l=D and if I manually enter the following URL in the address bar, for istance, https://www.website.com/allnames/D/2, the browser shows the allnames.php page with all the names, like no letter is selected.

Comment: @WeeMan "but unfortunately I can still see the original URL `website.com/allnames.php?l=D`" - Your first rule (which you said "works fine") should handle that? And presumably a URL of the form `/allnames/D` already "works" as intended and narrows selection to Ds only? Please edit your question to include your complete `.htaccess` file. This directive is only part of the puzzle (and shouldn't be a necessary part to make it "work").

Comment: Yes, the rule I originally posted was working fine, but only when I was on the first page of a specific letter which is normal since that rule can only handle 1 variable. I've posted the whole content of the htaccess file in the post. Thanks a lot for the help so far!